# Approve modification on entity before publish

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data

I am trying to create a system that requires an admin to approve a modification to an entity before being published. This system is a REST API with authentication/authorization already working, so that part is not important. Let's assume we have a model depicting an article, with a title and a body. A normal user is allowed to modify all the fields, but before the article is published, it must be approved by an admin. But while the article is in ``approval mode'', the old version of the article must be accessible by the REST API so to at least have a version that works (and the API does not return a 404).

The requirements are:

- I am using Spring Data and PostgreSQL so the one that gives me less headaches while integrating it is the one I am going with
- The less tinkering with weird checks, the better
- If possible, it should be modifiable to be used with other entities
- If possible, I would like to keep the old versions and who modified them. Non essential but would be nice

I have two different ideas, but I am not sure which one is the best one:

1. Create an abstract parent class, and then extend it with an approved and a non-approved version. Then, when the modification is approved the entity is transformed into an approved one and the API will return the new version:

```java
    public abstract class Article {}
    public class ApprovedArticle extends Article {}
    public class ModifiedArticle extends Article {}
```

2. Create a separate table where the modified entities are stored, and restrict the view to be admin only. In this case I would isolate the two types and make it easier when fetching info. But I am losing the ``history'' this way and I need to fetch from two different locations.
3. Simple boolean flag: this is my last resort, and I would love to avoid it!

Is there a better way or should I use one of the outlined examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look into spring Auditing.

https://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa

So there is an idea:
for each table you have a history table, each history table has **REVTYPE( “0” for adding, “1” for updating, “2” for removing an entity)** and **REV(change number)** columns.
Besides these, you need an extra table named REVINFO will be generated by default, to have user details you need to extend default DefaultRevisionEntity class.

```
@Entity
@RevisionEntity(YOURRevisionListener.class)
@Table(name = "your_audit_info")
@AttributeOverrides(
    {@AttributeOverride(name = "timestamp", column = @Column(name = "REVTSTMP")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "REV"))})

    public class AuditInfo extends DefaultRevisionEntity
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8458400378132903089L;
        @Column(name = "UpdateUser", nullable = false)
        private String userName;

        public String getUserName()
        {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(
            final String userName)
        {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

    }
```

with audit set up, you get user details if the change approved by admin then compare revisions number when the operation started and operation approved to avoid overwriting by others.

```
 @PrePersist
    public void onPrePersist() {
        audit("INSERT");
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void onPreUpdate() {
        audit("UPDATE");
    }

    @PreRemove
    public void onPreRemove() {
        audit("DELETE");
    }
```

I know it is a very high-level approach, but it can work in your case